# How can i declare ^\ in a string or character

Tags: c#

I would like to declare `^\` this as a string or character. I used the below but i am getting an error

```
 string str="^\";
```

So can any one help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape the backslash.

```
string str = "^\\";
```

Or, you can use the verbatim syntax.

```
string str = @"^\";
```

Comment: But i am getting the output as `^//` but i need exactly as i mentioned

Comment: @Vivekh: You need to make sure they are backslashes "^\\", not forward slashes "^//".

Comment: Jason i used this `string str = @"^\";` but i am getting as i specified `^//`

Comment: I don't understand (and from the question, probably noone else will either). What are you doing that you're getting a carat and 2 forward slashes when you're input is a carat and a backslash?  There's more to the puzzle here than you've given.

Comment: @Vivekh: The debugger will show the double backslash, but it's not part of the string (for example, try displaying it with `Console.WriteLine` if this is a console app).

Answer (score 3):

`\` is the escape token, you have to double it to use it as a literal in a string:

```
string str = "^\\";
```

Alternatively, you can use literal string syntax:

```
string str = @"^\";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape backslash characters, so instead of:

```
string str = "^\";
```

use:

```
string str = "^\\";
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about C#, but can you try:

```
string str="^\\";
```